# Why is Topology used to analyze circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why is Topology used to analyze circuits? Why aren't Kirchoff's laws and other laws specific to electrical engineering enough to analyze these circuits?
More specifically speaking, could someone give the example of a circuit that would be very difficult to analyze using Kirchoff's laws (and other laws), but becomes easier on using Topology?

This might come across as a rather amateur-ish question, but I have hard to look for the answer to such a question, and failed. Many apologies if this question does not meet the standards of this site, but I think think it is relevant to the main motivation behind forming this forum.

Thanks

Comment: How are you supposed to apply those laws if you don't understand the topology of the circuit?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams- I understand that understanding even a simple layout requires topology. However, I refer to solving circuits based only on a high school knowledge of Kirchoff's laws, as compared to solving complicated circuits using topology. Do we have an example of a circuit that would be close to impossible to analyze using a high school knowledge of physics, but gets simple when we use topology? I want to convince someone that Topology is not a useless addition to circuit analysis.

Comment: I also don't quite understand what you are asking.  The term "topology" for electrical circuits refers to the fact that analyzing current loops ends up involving aspects which reducing to studying the loops in the underlying graph of a circuit.  The study of such loops is exactly the field of algebraic topology, in one dimension.

Comment: @MathEE- Reading my comment might give you a better indication of what I'm looking for. I'm looking to convince someone of the fact that it is not practical to analyze all circuits using high school physics, and that topology makes life easier in circuit analysis.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to explain what *you* think "topology" means then we could start to clear this up.

Comment: "topology" is a large and sophisticated branch of mathematics, and "topology" is also the abstract connectivity of a graph-like structure without regard for the layout of its physical representation.

Answer (score 1):

Circuit simulators are as common as muck these days. You connect a bunch of components, add a power source, possibly attach an input signal generator and press the button.

Do you think that most simulators understand the topology of the circuit?

On the other hand, there are web based fixed-topology solvers that algebraicly solve a problem based on values of resistors and capacitance entered by the user. Any topology recognition going on here?

Much less these days, folk do things manually and of course, recognition of the sub-topologies of the  sub-circuits makes the problem easier to solve.

Take your pick as to your answer. All three methods are valid in my book.